# Scrape image's metadata from Facebook public posts

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This is a follow-up question in my quest to get some data from Facebook public posts. I'm trying to collect images metadata this time (image's url). Link posts work fine but some posts return empty data. I used the same approach suggested in answers to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309624/scrape-original-links-and-headlines-from-facebook-posts) but it doesn't work for the example below. Will appreciate suggestions!

```
link = "https://www.facebook.com/228735667216/posts/10151653129902217"
res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
comment = res.text.replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(comment, "lxml")
image = soup.find("div", class_="uiScaledImageContainer _517g")
img = image.find("img", class_="scaledImageFitWidth img")
href = img["src"]
print(href)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log in using `requests` is not that easy so I intentionally skipped that library. You can try using only `selenium` or `selenium` in combination with `BeautifulSoup` to do the doing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://www.facebook.com/228735667216/posts/10156284868312217"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#This is how you can make the browser headless
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#The following line controls the notification popping up right after login
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("your_username")
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("your_password",Keys.RETURN)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for img in soup.find_all(class_="scaledImageFitWidth"):
    print(img.get("src"))
driver.quit()
```

Output are like (partial):

```
https://external.fdac17-1.fna.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBjBuP0TBYabtnO&w=540&h=282&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fprod-cust-photo-posts-jfaikqealaka%2F3065-6e4c325b07b921fdefed4dd727881f8d.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=1&fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&_nc_hash=AQCVKXMSqvNiHZik
https://external.fdac17-1.fna.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCJ6RFOF4dY2xTn&w=100&h=100&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.images.express.co.uk%2Fimg%2Fdynamic%2F106%2F750x445%2F1046936.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=1&fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher_square&_nc_hash=AQAyFxRaZTGV47Se
```

Comment: Thanks! Need to turn off 2-factor verification for that. I have actually switched to Graph API in the end. Much faster. But this is useful!